# wav layers for sequencer

Tags: audio

I need to play .wav files on top of each other and at different times for an app that can return beats with drum samples there a class  or method to implement this?

All I have been able to do so far is play wav files in sequence.

Comment: In what programming language, on what platform?

Comment: oh apologies mate its in c# and on wp7

Answer (score 1):

Think you can do this by loading each sample in a SoundEffect class and calling the Play method depending on your timing.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.audio.soundeffect.aspx

The other way is to use a MediaStreamSource and mix the raw wav data together before feeding it to the GetSampleAsync method.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.mediastreamsource(v=vs.95).aspx

Comment: +1 for mixing.  This is by far the better way to do this, making playback much more accurate and controllable.